# Can I run a torrent started in Windows, on Ubuntu, in dual boot setup?

Tags: windows, kubuntu, utorrent

So I have a torrent running windows downloading files. Having my machine setup with Ubuntu + Windows dual boot, can I pause the running torrent in Windows, boot into Ubuntu, and resume the torrent there?

If I were to copy torrent download files of Windows's `%LOCALAPPDATA%/qBittorent/BT_backup/*` to relevant Linux directory, would it work ?

The software used is qBittorent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with one caveat: `*.fastresume` files specify the absolute path for torrents and they are naturally incompatible with Linux.

How I'd approach that:

- Do not use or copy this directory
- Download and open the appropriate torrent files again
- Specify the save path where they are already downloaded to, **uncheck** "Start now" (it should be unchecked by default)
- Right click the torrent and choose "Force recheck"

Now you can start seeding or continue downloading it.